# how to use http response header to name my download file using Android DownloadManger

Tags: android, filenames

I'm using Android's DownloadManger service to get a apk,and the apk'file name is in the http response header , is there a good way to get the file name ,and use this name in the DownloadManger?

Comment: I think the filename is in the full URL, so why have to use header?

Comment: the web service is not written by me ,and alse Can't be changed